# iText 7 dynamic page header issue

Tags: itext7

I am trying to create dynamic page header with itext7 using EventHandlers. I am using the below code for this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C:\\Test\\variable_header.pdf");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new VariableHeader().manipulatePdf(DEST);
}

protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
    VariableHeaderEventHandler handler = new VariableHeaderEventHandler();
    pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, handler);
    handler.setHeader("First Header");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        doc.add(new Paragraph("Added First content"));
     }
    doc.add(new AreaBreak());
    handler.setHeader("Second Header");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        doc.add(new Paragraph("Added Second content"));
    }
    doc.close();
}

protected class VariableHeaderEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
    protected String header;

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent documentEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        try {
            new PdfCanvas(documentEvent.getPage())
                    .beginText()
                    .setFontAndSize(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA), 12)
                    .moveText(450, 806)
                    .showText(header)
                    .endText()
                    .stroke();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here I created 'VariableHeaderEventHandler' that renders the dynamic page header for every page of the document.

Initially I set the page header as "First Header" and added the text "Added First content" to the document for 50 times. Then I added the Area break which leaves the further part of the page empty after rendering the previous contents and any further contents will be rendered in a new page. Then I changed the page header as "Second Header" and added the text "Added Second content" to the document for 15 times.

So as per the above code, the page header "Second Header" should be rendered ONLY from the page where the text "Added Second content" is being displayed. But the "Second Header" is rendered in the previous page where the text "Added First content" is displayed as shown below:

iText7 Dynamic header issue:

[image: Screenshot]

It looks like there is some issue with the Event Handling mechanism in iText 7.0.1.

Is there some way to solve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You are using low-level events of `PdfDocument` along with high-level layout via `Document`. `END_PAGE` event is triggered when a page is flushed to the output stream. Although low-level `PdfDocument` and high-level `Document` are related, there is no contract that `Document` flushes the page immediately after it goes to a new one. In fact, `Document` does flush pages *with some delay* by default which is required by more fine-grained layout capabilities. The fact that the pages are flushed with some delay causes newly-set header appear on "older" pages with first type of content. So this is expected behavior, at least for now.

There are many ways to get around that behavior and achieve what you want. I will tell about one of them.

After you have added the `AreaBreak` to the `Document`, you can ask the `DocumentRenderer` for the current area available for rendering the rest of the content and this area will contain the current page number:

```
doc.add(new AreaBreak());
int secondContentStartPageNumber = doc.getRenderer().getCurrentArea().getPageNumber();
```

You can then pass that information to your event handler:

```
handler.setSecondAreaStartPage(secondContentStartPageNumber);
```

And use that information when deciding which header to output for a page:

```
int pageNumber = documentEvent.getDocument().getPageNumber(documentEvent.getPage());
String textToShow = pageNumber < secondAreaStartPage ? firstHeader : secondHeader;
```

The full `VariableHeaderEventHandler` class would look like this:

```
protected class VariableHeaderEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
    private String firstHeader = "First Header";
    private String secondHeader = "Second Header";
    private int secondAreaStartPage = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    public void setSecondAreaStartPage(int newValue) {
        secondAreaStartPage = newValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent documentEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        int pageNumber = documentEvent.getDocument().getPageNumber(documentEvent.getPage());
        try {
            new PdfCanvas(documentEvent.getPage())
                    .beginText()
                    .setFontAndSize(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA), 12)
                    .moveText(450, 806)
                    .showText(pageNumber < secondAreaStartPage ? firstHeader : secondHeader)
                    .endText()
                    .stroke();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course for the case of more than two areas the code will become more complicated, but this is more of a programming exercise than a question about iText.

Comment: This does feel more complicated than the commonplace itext 5 implementation of the same task. In particular if you want the current chapter and section in header or footer or something similarly dynamic...

Comment: I have this exact same problem in a Section Title for a footer; it was working great in iText5, then I ported it over and I've been tearing my hair out over it, trying to figure out why I was calling newPage and not having an event fire :P Thanks for the solution... and @mkl, I definitely agree, it was a lot simpler in iText5 to do this....